# Active Directory Multisite Planning

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008, exchange-server

Here are the details of my plan:

Three Site office in three different states.
All running pfsense IPsec VPN.
1 site with Windows Server 2003 R2 DC and other 2 with windows server 2008 R2 DC.
All 3 domain controllers are its self DNS servers.

The image explains my scenario little bit. I want to get your feedback about it? I need to plan it so that multiple sites get replicated and if one of the DC gets down or VPN service crashes, the other sites DC serve the user request.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/by5vk

Here is what i think.

demote all the DCs.
Create a single forest and 3 different domains.
Configure Active directory sites and services using VPN.
Allow DS to communicate from the firewall on both IPSec and WAN interface.

Comment: I don't see a programming question here. Perhaps this should be moved to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want three seperate domains - that won't meet your requirement. The setup as it stands now (one domain, 3 DCs) will meet your requirements. Ensure the DCs can replicate through the VPN tunnels and that the site/subnet topology is configured to match.